# Как вернуть число из списка его цифр?

Tags: python, python-3.5

Я сделал список из числа:

```
digits = list(str(number))
```

Как вернуть исходное число из списка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
number = 15
number = list(str(number))
print(type(number)) #печатает <class 'list'>
num = ""
for n in number:
    num += n
num = int(num)
print(num, type(num)) #печатает 15 <class 'int'>
```

Comment: можеш обьяснить что к чему тут?

Comment: Определяем переменную number, преобразуем ее к списку, потом создаем пустую строку и в цикле присоединяем к ней символы из спивку, после чего приводим данную строку к типу int.

Comment: спасибо но так как нужно больше символов напишу ещо єто

Answer (score 4):

Можно так:

```
number = int(''.join(number))
```

Здесь `''.join(number)` объединяет список в строку, а `int()` делает из строки число.

Comment: а почему он обьединяет в строку и как?или загуглить .джойн?

Comment: Метод строки `join` объединяет (производит контактенацию) всех элеменетов последовательности, переданной ему как аргумент, вставляя между элементами строку, для которой был вызван метод. То есть, представим, что у нас есть список `lst = ["foo", "bar", "buzz"]`, тогда если мы сделаем так `'+'.join(lst)`, то напечатается `'foo+bar+buzz'`.

Comment: для развлечения: `reduce(lambda number, digit: number*10 + digit, map(int, digits))`